# how to change python import path in multiple python installation?

Tags: python, python-import

I have python 2.7.8 and 2.7.13 installed on my pc.
I created a python 2.7.13 project from venv.  I confirmed that the virtual environment was using correct python version.  However, I noticed in the project a .py file in python 2.7.13 installation importing a file from 2.7.8 installation.  How can I change this behavior?

== new information found ==

It is very strange that in non venv mode, it imports files from correct python installation.  It happens only in venv.

I am very confused now.

Comment: How are you running your project? With which commands?

Comment: It is a flask project.  I am running with "set FLASK_APP=app.py, flask run" in windows command line